# jQuery in functions declared outside of document-ready, but called from within

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can a function declared and attached to the global scope, but having jQuery-dependent code, **always** be depended on to work properly if it is only ever called from within a jQuery document-ready block?

e.g.:

```
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></sript>
<script>

    function myFunc(){ alert( $('#someElem').text() ); }

    $(function(){  

       myFunct(); 
    })

</script>
```

In practice, I've seen this done a lot, with such functions being written to separate files entirely. I have never seen it fail, but part of me wonders whether or not this is truly safe.

I think at least partially this depends on whether document-ready waits for the completion of the javascript *compilation phase* of page-load. But are there other reasons this might fail?

Please disregard issues around polluting the global name-space, readability, and so forth. I am only concerned here with reliable execution.

Comment: It will not fail unless the other external files do not load...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really can't fail, the `$()` function that looks up the element is only executed when the `myFunc` function is executed, and that function only executes once `document.ready` fires, so the element will be available at that time.

The global `myFunc` function will also always be available, as long it's defined before the `document.ready` code in the DOM.

In many cases it will even be available if defined after the `document.ready` code as `DOMContentLoaded` (and other such methods) is async and waits for the DOM to be ready, but there's no guarantee that all scripts will be loaded at that time, just that the elements in the DOM are available, so you should generally make sure that the `myFunc` function is defined before the `$(function(){  ... });` code.

Answer (score 0):

Such constructs are written only if `myfunct()` will be accessible from outside the scope of `document.ready()`. If other functions / events may also call it, it is better to move it out.

If it is only intended to be called once or on a particular event, it may be nested in the calling function body only.

One may even like to make the function calls fully contained structures like clorjures, and the likes. In that case too, the function would be nested inside another `var` declaration.

Other than this, there seems no other big difference.

> Please add if I missed on anything!

Comment: Another case where the 'myfunct()' might appear outside the scope of 'document.ready()' is when an element is loaded dynamically. For example, jquery related to a modal window which is built and displayed on demand after the initial page load will not work *if included* in the 'document.ready()' block, but performs reliably if excluded.

Comment: I think the question wasn't so much about when to use a global function but if you can rely on a global function always being available at document ready